# How to get the object reference from a standard controller save()?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension

See the following VF Page controller extension:

```
public with sharing class IssueController {

    public Issue__c obj {get;set;}

    private ApexPages.StandardController stdController;

    public IssueController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.stdController = controller;
        obj = (Issue__c)controller.getRecord();
    }

    public PageReference doSave() {
        PageReference ret = stdController.save();
        system.assertNotEquals(null, obj.Id); // BOOM!
        return ret;
    }

}
```

I would like to know how (sort of parsing the page reference URL) to get the new `obj.Id` back?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're trying to get the Id, you should just go back to stdController.

```
Id issueId = stdController.getId();
```

I also very much doubt that this is getting the value from the query string, as the documentation suggests. I'm almost positive I've used this method in pages with no query params and it works. I'll try to test later and amend my answer based on those results.

Comment: Thanks Peter - It's almost as if `obj` was cloned somewhere along the line and the reference lost!

Comment: Yeah, basic "by reference" logic would suggest that you could go to either obj or stdController. But on the post-back, remember that properties are overridden with the view state. So perhaps if you made the assignment of getRecord() happen in the getter, it would allow you to successfully access obj.id. Either that or make obj transient.